# How to return updated array with inserted item after scan?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following code:

```
public checkedRoles$ = merge(this.roles$, this.roleChanged$).pipe(
    tap((data) => console.log(data)),
    scan((roles: Role[], role: Role) => {
        console.log(roles);
        return roles.map((r) => (role && r.roleId === role.roleId ? role : r));
    }),
    map((roles) => roles.filter((r) => r.checked)),
);
```

When I get updated array of objects `this.roles$` I can see result before scan: `tap((data) => console.log(data)),`

But I dont get this array inside `scan()` in  `console.log(roles);`. How always get fresh array with checked items?

This is simplest no Rxjs way I tried above:

```
private checkedRoles$ = new BehaviorSubject<any[]>([]);

readonly roleChangeSubject = new Subject<Role>();
roleChanged$ = this.roleChangeSubject.asObservable();
this.roleChanged$.subscribe((role: any) => {
            let roles = this.roles$.getValue();

            roles.forEach((r: Role) => {
                if (role.roleId === r.roleId) r.checked = role.checked;
            });

            this.checkedRoles$.next(roles);
        });
```

Comment: I get the problem, scan returns prev saved state, so I need somehow merge `this.roles$` with result from `scan()`:

Like this: `scan((roles: Role[], role: Role) => { [...roles, this.roles$]...}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should work as you expect. It's just that you are logging the previous `roles`, as you say, before the scan has returned.

You can see this if you add another `tap` after the `scan`:

```
public checkedRoles$ = merge(this.roles$, this.roleChanged$).pipe(
  tap((data) => console.log('New role change:', data)),
  scan((roles: Role[], role: Role) => {
    return roles.map((r) => (role && r.roleId === role.roleId ? role : r));
  }),
  tap((data) => console.log('Updated roles:', data)),
  map((roles) => roles.filter((r) => r.checked)),
);
```

On another note, `merge` is probably not right here as `roles$` and `roleChanged$` are different types.

If `roles$` only **emits once**, then you could use `concat` instead and then it will only be used as the initial value for `scan`:

```
public checkedRoles$ = concat(this.roles$, this.roleChanged$).pipe(
  scan((roles: Role[], role: Role) => {
    return roles.map((r) => (role && r.roleId === role.roleId ? role : r));
  }),
  map((roles) => roles.filter((r) => r.checked)),
);
```